# Run the code in main threa after completeion of IO thread process kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

  lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            networkviewModel.productist.collectLatest {
                when (it) {
                    Resource.Empty -> {
                        Log.e("product", "" + "empty")
                    }
                    is Resource.Failure -> {
                        Log.e("product", "" + "failure")
                    }
                    Resource.Loading -> {

                    }
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        val response = it.value
                        Log.e("test","success response")
                        val products: List<Products> = response.data
                        val variants: List<Variants> = response.data.map { it.variants }.flatten()
                        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            productRoom.insertProducts(products)
                            productRoom.insertVariants(variants)
                            val subcategoryid = SubCategoryList(response.data[0].subcategory_id!!.toInt())
                            productRoom.insertSubCat(subcategoryid)
                        }
                        subcat_id = response.data[0].subcategory_id!!.toInt()
                        roomviewModel.productFlow.collectLatest{
                            Log.e("test","flow success from network room")
                            //    Log.e("test",it.toString())
                            LoadingUtils.hideDialog()
                            proadapter.setMutableArraylist(it)
                            proadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

i got error of
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.store.pasumainew, PID: 13125
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

because in Resource.Success -> collect called before the completion of IO thread process

I want to complete the IO thread and afterwards collect the value from room

Comment: Just don’t launch a child coroutine for that process. You can make those calls directly if they are defined as suspend functions. Don’t need to worry about using Dispatchers.IO unless you are calling blocking functions. Room suspend functions do not block.

Comment: Room operations can't be called in main thread..thats y i am using Dispatchers.IO @Tenfour04

Comment: Yes they can if defined as suspend functions. That’s the point of suspend functions, that they don’t block. They can be called from any dispatcher. If for some reason you *did* have to call a blocking function, you would use `withContext` instead of launching a child coroutine, but again, that is unnecessary with Room suspend functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` before collecting, it will be suspended until all operations are complete:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {                
    productRoom.insertProducts(products)
    productRoom.insertVariants(variants)
    val subcategoryid = SubCategoryList(response.data[0].subcategory_id!!.toInt())
    productRoom.insertSubCat(subcategoryid)
}
// ... collecting code
```

Btw you don't need to use `Dispatchers.Main` to launch the main coroutine, by default `lifecycleScope` works on `Dispatchers.Main` context, so you can just write:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash is in this line of code

```
val subcategoryid = SubCategoryList(response.data[0].subcategory_id!!.toInt())
```

try changing it to this

```
val subcategoryid = SubCategoryList(response.data[0]?.subcategory_id?.toInt())?:0
```